# Problem with Bitcoin Core’s regression test mode

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, rpc-error-25

I have started bitcoin daemon with -regtest flag. The output was

> Bitcoin server starting

But, when I run

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
```

command, it shows

> error: couldn't connect to server: unknown (code -1) (make sure server
>   is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)

How this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing port number in bitcoin.conf.
open file

```
nano ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

add new line

> rpcport=18332;

save the file and restart bitcoind

Comment: This is only the regtest RPC port then?

Comment: This will effect all instances of `bitcoind` that are started, regardless of network.

Comment: @Willtech I think it is

Answer (score 1):

Adding *rpcport=18332* **temporarily** solve your problem. If you want to run **mainnet** or **testnet** at the same time when **regtest** is running, you *wont be able to use them*, it is because when you assign `rpcport=xyz` all  bitcoin instances will try to interact through same rpcport when daemon is started but at one time only single daemon can access single port number.But in your case all three daemons tries to take rpcport as 18332.

Infact what you can do is, try to get connected to default rpc port for regtest by typing command:

> bitcoind -regtest -daemon -rpcport=18443

```
Mainnet:8332 
Testnet:18332 
Regtest:18443`
```

*Note:For bitcore v15 rpc port is same for testnet and mainnet where as in v16 rpc port is diffrent for all of them*

Comment: From their docs, for testnet&regtest port is same. ie.18832. Is there a different port for regtest?!

Comment: @Prayagk   For bitcore v15 rpc port is same for testnet and mainnet where as in v16 rpc port is diffrent for all of them

Comment: ok..that's new for me

Comment: you can see which version you using with command getinfo